# WCF Client best practice

Tags: c#, performance, wcf

We are facing timeout issue when calling some of the WCF Operations.

We are not explicitly closing the connection. Could this be causing the issue? The number of users on site is pretty low and maxconcurrentsession on server is set to 150.

We have 20 methods on client side that calls the service. Do we need to do below on all the methods that call service?

1. Open Connection
2. Call Service
3. Close Connection
4. Any exception Abort.

If we don't close the connection, does WCF automatically closes the connection?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of operations will be performed using those methods?

Comment: One instance that always fail on create is read, update and create operations in sequence. Other times mostly read and update.

Answer (score 0):

You should do 4 step above.

If you don't close connection. Anytime service meet an error, you cann't call service on existent connection. Error such as:

> The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, 
>       cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.

Refer for best practices: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/622989/WCF-and-the-Try-Catch-Abort-Pattern

Comment: The OP's wcf client is throwing a timeout exception. This is not the same error you get when calling via a faulted channel. I am not sure how your answer helps.

Answer (score -1):

WCF service operations has default value of sendTimeOut is 1 Minute. To increase it you can set this value in both either in coding or in configuration.

From [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx):

> 1. SendTimeout – used to initialize the OperationTimeout, which governs the whole process of sending a message, including receiving a
>      reply message for a request/reply service operation. This timeout also
>      applies when sending reply messages from a callback contract method.
> 2. OpenTimeout – used when opening channels when no explicit timeout value is specified
> 3. CloseTimeout – used when closing channels when no explicit timeout value is specified

You need to update value in client as well as in server configuration (Or Update on service and then Update client Proxies) as below, this will set all timeout values to 10 minute.

```
<configuration>
<system.serviceModel>
  <bindings>
    <wsHttpBinding>
      <binding openTimeout="00:10:00"
               closeTimeout="00:10:00"
               sendTimeout="00:10:00"
               receiveTimeout="00:10:00">
      </binding>
    </wsHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: This appears to have been taken, almost word-for-word, from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh924831(v=vs.110).aspx. When you copy verbatim from an online source, you MUST quote the source. I have fixed it for you.

Comment: Additionally, it appears you don't really understand SendTimeout - this is not something you set on the service operation, it is a client-side setting for the client binding configuration. It will have no effect if you set it on the service. The article you linked to actually says this. You should edit your answer to make this clear.